# How to switch between GPU's  on HP Pavilion DV7 Laptop?

Tags: 12.04, graphics, laptop, hp, gpu

I have two GPUs in my HP DV7 Laptol and I wonder how to switch GPU I'm using at the moment?

I have `ATI Radeon HD 4200M` and `ATI Radeon HD 6600M` running on my laptop and I want to change from HD 4200M to HD 6600M.

Answer (score 0):

I myself had got a Laptop with two GPUs . They also supported auto-switching technology. Now when i installed ubuntu, I ran into a similar problem that when auto-switching is done, It could not switch completely which resulted into erroneous screen, ending up in unexpected system shutdown.
 What worked for me was to edit my kernel boot details first as:

```
grep -i switcheroo /boot/config-2.6.*
```

and setting the essential options for GPU switching(Which obviously I googled)

The condition is: **The vga_switcheroo mechanism will only be active when the kernel is booted with either the "modeset=1" kernel option, and/or the "nomodeset" option being absent**

Now after making the above mentioned configurations, test if vga switching works by:

```
ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

and if that works, you can try out the advanced methods for vedio switching as mentioned in [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics).

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I use command

**ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch**

it gives me access denied and when I run it as root it complains that file / directory does not exist.

Comment: why not you try to run as user the command `echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` ,does that work?

Comment: OK, well you would also like to see [this](http://asusm51ta-with-linux.blogspot.in/) article if it might give you some solution