# UBUNTU installed on USB flashdrive not booting on HP Pavilion DV7 6b00et (Not Llive)

Tags: 12.04, boot, hp

I installed Ubuntu 12.4 on 8GB USB Flash drive. It went OK. But when I reboot it goes to Blank screen. IF I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> the (GRUB loading) msg on screen. Fan starts so I assume ATI HD6770M graphics card gets control. I've to press and hold power key to close.

BIOS is set to dynamic but changing to fixed doesn't help. Flash drive boots ok on my 32bit desktop. How can I turn ATI card off using Live-USB? ATI card has no problem with WIN7, HP will not help. I've been trying to reinstall ATI drivers, Changing boot options in Grub but nothing helped.

Driver HP dv7-6b00et

At this point, I've tried this:
I selected to stop ATI card.  Used a live-USB, Mounted ubuntu.
Installed flashdrive, chrooted, and became root.
Edited `/etc/rc.local` to add: 
`modprobe radeon`
`echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`

The `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf` file was empty so `/etc/rc.local`:
`add blacklist fglrx`
REBOOT ===> blank screen

I make /etc/rc.local EXECUTABLE

Comment: Current: Bios set to FIXED and GPU of INTEL selected.RADEON gpu is not ACTIVE.

Answer (score 1):

The HP DV7 notebooks are not fully compatible with Linux, especially the AMD Radeon graphics.

There are multiple threads about this issue on Ubuntu's official forums, but I am uncertain what the best options are.  Here are some threads/pages you should read before considering your options.

Description of Hybrid Graphics and instructions on how to disable the Radeon graphics if using the open-source drivers: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Instructions for updating Catalyst drivers: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11900678

Reference to a thread about disabling the Radeon graphics, poster considers it the best option: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1917897&highlight=dv7

Instructions for turning off AMD Radeon graphics: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1917897&highlight=dv7 *******

Similar thread here on AskUbuntu: [How to switch between GPU's  on HP Pavilion DV7 Laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133364/how-to-switch-between-gpus-on-hp-pavilion-dv7-laptop)

Long thread about... well, I have no idea, but it's long: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450 *******

******* ***Be aware that these threads were started prior to 12.04's official release and may contain outdated information***

I don't have an exact answer for you, as I have not dealt with the incompatibility issues myself (though I was definitely looking into buying an HP DV7), but the links explain your options and have step-by-step instructions.

Comment: I edit   /etc/rc.local  add

Comment: modprobe radeon
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

Comment: Problem is Grub bootloader. İnstalled PCLINUXOS on usb hdd and stick

Comment: Installed PCLINUSOS on USBHDD and USB stick both Boots OK. Bootloader is vmlinux

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael
I selected to stop ATI card.
USED live-USB, Mounted ubuntu installed flashdrive 
chrooted and became root.
Edited  two files
/etc/rc.local     add:
modprobe radeon
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
and 
 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf
file was empty so I copied first 2 lines of /etc/rc.local
add blacklist fglrx
add exit 0
REBOOT ===> blank screen
Should I make these two files EXECUTABLE if yes how?